# how to read a random line from 2 files and put them together

Tags: html, wordpress, bash

so I tried `shuf -n 1 filename` in bash and it showed me a random line, but I want to be able to do this on my own website with 2 files and the outputs combined.

for example my files are

```
file 1
one one
five eight
one two three

file 2 
canada
usa
netherland
```

so the output would be "five eight usa" or "one one netherland"

Does anyone know any code that can help me start this?

Comment: what server-side language capabilities do you have? php, asp, etc.?

Comment: im gonna be using wordpress or wix for start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With paste, shuf and bash's process substitution:

```
paste -d " " <(shuf -n 1 file1) <(shuf -n 1 file2)
```

Output (example):

```
one two three canada
```